# DDD: is it ok to contain list of entity inside an aggregate root

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I am developing a client application for searching flights tickets. I have obtained a JSON with search result from server and I should express this result to client.

Suppose I have a `Fare`, `AirlineCompany` and `AviaTicketSearchResult` objects. `AviaTicketSearchResult` should contain list of `AirlineCompany` objects. Each `AirlineCompany` should contain `Fare`s. And I guess that `AviaTicketSearchResult` and `AirlineCompany` are an Aggregate root, because I have the rule of Cascading Delete, when I delete `AirlineCompany` it make sense to delete all airlineCompany's fares same with `AviaTicketSearchResult`.

1) Is it ok to contain list of `Fare`s inside an aggregate root (`AirlineCompany`)?

Another problem is that I should to have a filter ability for `Fare`s inside `AirlineCompany`. Each Fare has a itinerary and every itinerary has a list of variants (`ItineraryVariant`) (different legs, travel etc.). When I accept the filter I should update my `AirlineCompany` and remove unnecessary `Fare`s or remove unnecessary `ItineraryVariant` inside concrete `Fare`.

2) How to apply ability of filtering?

I am assuming that I should represent Fare as VO and recreate Fare object from raw data (json) each time when I apply the filter and then add it to AirlineCompany after all update AviaTicketSearchResult with filtered AirlineCompany.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that Domain-Driven Design is a good fit here. As far as I can tell you're just talking about a couple of DTOs for the UI and some means to filter them.

Domain-Driven Design comes in handy when you're trying to grasp (and model) complex behavior. View Models or DTOs should be as simple as possible. Most of the time there's no need for sophisticated and time-consuming modeling efforts.

Or, as Eric Evans puts it:

> Focus on the Core Domain

Comment: I have wrapped my domain model with Service layer, UI have a reference to ServiceFacade that return DTO object back to UI.

Comment: And this task is only part of complex application. After showing result, user should choose concrete Fare and create Order with selected fare.

Comment: @tikhop As you state this is a part of a complex application and DDD may be applied in other parts of the application, specifically parts that will handle the creation of orders. This particular part however does not involve aggregates and VOs. You have DTOs that may correspond to aggregates, but they aren't aggregates themselves. As such, you can structure the DTOs in a way that best represents the data - just basic OOP. You don't need to worry about such things as consistency boundaries, persistence, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is it ok to contain list of Fares inside an aggregate root
>   (AirlineCompany)?

Yes, especially if AirlineCompany is really your aggregate root which MAY be the case.  From your question, I think you might could benefit from learning more about the problem domain.  Should AirlineCompany really be an aggregate root or it is just a name to the customer?  Maybe Fare should really be the aggregate root and AirlineCompany should just be a string property on Fare.  Be careful not to over model and focus on the problem domain.  If your customer is someone purchasing tickets, I doubt that they are as focused on the AirlineCompany as they are the Fare and Itineraries.  When modelling the problem domain, things like JSON and VO should be temporarily forgotten about.

> 2) How to apply ability of filtering?

It should be the responsibility of your repository or domain service to filter the results based on the filter parameters.  The implementation of this is up to you.  Generally, however, if the client is communicating to a server, the server would run the repository application code which, depending on your implementation, can pass that onto the db server allowing you to achieve the best possible performance so that you're not passing extraneous data around.